# Row bind nested dataframe within list

Tags: r, tidyr, purrr

I was hoping someone could help me with a problem I have.  I have a `json` response that is in list format.

The structure is a list.  Within each list there is a column players.  It's nested within each list as such

`df[[1]]$body$wildcards$players`

The `players` column is a nested `df` within each list.  How would I bind the players column nested `df` for the full list?

Reprex of screenshot below.

```
sample <- list(
  list(
    body = list(
      wildcards = list(
        players = data.frame(
          firstname = c("Fernando", "Jon"),
          throws = c("L", "R")
        )
      ),
      statusMessage = "OK",
      statusCode = 200
    )
  ),
  list(
    body = list(
      wildcards = list(
        players = data.frame(
          firstname = c("Eduardo", "James"),
          throws = c("L", "R")
        )
      ),
      statusMessage = "OK",
      statusCode = 200
    )
  )
)
```

Here's a screenshot of the structure:
[image: JSON]

Output `df`

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~firstname, ~throws,
  "Fernando",     "L",
       "Jon",     "R",
   "Eduardo",     "L",
     "James",     "R"
  )
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a small example that mimics the issue for testing

Comment: I added a sample list.

Comment: what would be the expected output for this

Comment: Do you need `tibble(col1 = sample) %>% unnest(c(col1)) %>% unnest_wider(c(col1)) %>% unnest(c(wildcards)) %>% unnest(c(wildcards))`

Comment: Added output df.  I'm looking to row bind the df from players in both lists within the list.

Comment: thanks, can you please check my soluiton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `pluck` with `map`

```
library(purrr)
map_dfr(sample, ~ pluck(.x, 'body', 'wildcards','players'))
#  firstname throws
#1  Fernando      L
#2       Jon      R
#3   Eduardo      L
#4     James      R
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the same column names in each dataframes :

```
library(data.table)
new_df <- rbindlist(lapply(df,function(x)x$body$wildcards$players),use.names=T,fill=T)
```

Pay attention that you don't have the same number of columns in each df, so with `fill=T` argument you will have `NA`s in your dataframe.

Does this solve your problem ?